# Get highest zorder object from matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given a matplotlib figure or plot, how can I retrieve the value of the highest zorder object? For instance, retrieving the value of `5` in this example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(np.arange(10), np.arange(10), zorder=5, linewidth=5)
ax.plot(np.arange(10), np.arange(10)[::-1], zorder=1, linewidth=5)
# implement: get_maximum_zorder(ax)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by accessing the axes's children, each of which has a `zorder` attribute.

```
max([_.zorder for _ in ax.get_children()])
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer gets the z-order of *every* object on the figure.

```
print (ax.get_children())

# [matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x104E63F0,
# matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x104E6670,
# matplotlib.spines.Spine object at 0x0E6976D0,
# matplotlib.spines.Spine object at 0x0E697770,
# matplotlib.spines.Spine object at 0x0E697810,
# matplotlib.spines.Spine object at 0x0E6978B0,
# matplotlib.axis.XAxis object at 0x0E697950>,
# matplotlib.axis.YAxis object at 0x104CB170>,
# Text(0.5,1,''), Text(0,1,''), Text(1,1,''),
# matplotlib.patches.Rectangle object at 0x104DC4F0]
```

If you wanted to narrow down the search to only include the lines on the figure, you could get a list of lines using `ax.lines` then loop over these calling the [`get_zorder()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_zorder.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_zorder) function:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(np.arange(10), np.arange(10), zorder=5, linewidth=5)
ax.plot(np.arange(10), np.arange(10)[::-1], zorder=1, linewidth=5)

lines = ax.lines
print (max(line.get_zorder() for line in lines))
# 5

# You can use .zorder here too!
# print (max(line.zorder for line in lines))
```

As pointed out by @tom in the comments, you can replace `ax.lines` with `ax.collections`, `ax.patches` and `ax.artists` depending on the kind of plot being used

Comment: to extend this to other kinds of plots, the user may also want to get `zorder`s from items in `ax.collections`, `ax.patches` and `ax.artists`, not just `ax.lines`